# AudioKit can't record when I write AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) in AppDelegate in the recorder demo

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    debugPrint("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }catch{

    }
    UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()//设置后台播放
}
```

then it can't record,and when I delete these code,it worked

Comment: Set an appropriate category for session in order to record. E.g. `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`

Comment: @VadimPopov You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the right category (you are currently using playback) for the session and preform these in the right order. Use either `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` or `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` and call SetActive **afterwards**. Here is the code with error catching.

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
         do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print (error)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print (error)
        }
```